# How can I get the individual points and their attributes from a scatterplot in pyqtgraph?

Tags: pyqt, python-3.6, pyqtgraph

I was able to create a ScatterPlotItem in pyqtgraph without a hitch by promoting a Graphics View widget to a PlotWidget in Qt Designer. I plotted some random data on it and now I want to access the individual points I click on. The docs say that one can connect the sigClicked(self, points) signal, which, in theory, should return the points under the cursor. But that does not seem to be the case, because when I click on a point I get the same object regardless of which point I clicked. I suspect that this signal returns the entire ScatterPlotItem and not any specific point.

Here is my code so far:

```
import sys, time
from timeit import default_timer as timer

from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, Qt, QPoint, QUrl, QEvent
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtMultimedia
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
import pyqtgraph as pg

import numpy as np

class ScatterExample(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        # Main Loop
        super(ScatterExample, self).__init__()
        loadUi('<path/to/ui file>.ui', self)
        self.setWindowTitle('ScatterExample')

        self.scatter = pg.ScatterPlotItem(pxMode=False, pen=pg.mkPen(width=1, color='g'), symbol='t', size=1)
        self.scatter.sigClicked.connect(self.onPointsClicked)
        self.Scatter_Plot_View.addItem(self.scatter) # Scatter_Plot_View is the Graphics View I promoted to PlotWidget
        n = 5
        print('Number of points: ' + str(n))
        data = np.random.normal(size=(2, n))
        pos = [{'pos': data[:, i]} for i in range(n)]

        now = pg.ptime.time()
        self.scatter.setData(pos)
        print(self.scatter.data)


    def onPointsClicked(self, points):
        print('Ain\'t getting individual points ', points)
        points.setPen('b', width=2) # this turns EVERY point blue, not just the one clicked.
```

The above print statement prints:

```
Ain't getting individual points <pyqtgraph.graphicsItems.ScatterPlotItem.ScatterPlotItem object at 0x000001C36577F948>
```

How can I get the points I click on and their corresponding attributes, such as x and y coordinates?

Comment: change `def onPointsClicked(self, points):` to `def onPointsClicked(self, obj, points):`

Comment: Thank you! It worked! I am yet to wrap my head around the way those classes work.

Answer (score 0):

As eyllansec was kind enough to suggest, I changed my `def onPointsClicked(self, points):` to `def onPointsClicked(self, obj, points):` and now pyqtgraph works a expected.